# Any way to change the position of the /title command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When using the `/title` command it displays right in the center, I was wondering if there was any to display it somewhat to the left or right. I have tried using invisible characters but Minecraft just ignores them when rendering it. So, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you had suggested about using "invisible characters" is the correct approach to this problem, it is likely you were not using the correct ones.

A normal title command looks as follows:

```
/title @a title {"text":"This is a title!"}
```

And will show in the center:
[image]

However, after adding the "invisible characters":

```
/title @a title {"text":" \u0020 \u0020 \u0020 \u0020 \u0020This is a title!"}
```

The title will be skewed to the right:
[image]

To skew a title to the left, you would simply add the characters after the text instead of before it:

```
/title @a title {"text":"This is a title!\u0020 \u0020 \u0020 \u0020 \u0020 "}
```

Which will yield:
[image]

Mess around with different amounts of these characters until you reach the desired result.